# Display image in browser from storage laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

How can i display image form storage

My images are in storage/uploads folder

Iam doing this`< img src="{{Storage::url($user->image)}}" >`

I have also done `php artisan storage:link`

My url is

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/fU46qscYTreoFzeKLMBfCVb0uceuvGlAMhNPwozH.png
```

I am getting `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

How can i get image `< img src="{{Storage::url($user->image)}}" >` ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a symbolic link, you now should have a symlink from public/storage to storage/app/public. Please check if it is working or not.
If yes, then you can access those files by using:

```
<img src="{{asset(map_storage_path_to_link($user->image) )}}">
```